# Не могу остановить скрипт

Tags: javascript, canvas, события

```js
window.onload = function() {

  var start = document.getElementById('start');
  var stop = document.getElementById('stop');
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var choosenPos = getSquare();
  var choosenSpeed = getSpeed();
  var currentPos = 0;

  function getSquare() {
    var pos = Math.floor(Math.random() * (640 - 1) + 1);
    return pos;
  }


  function getSpeed() {
    var speed = Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 - 1) + 1);
    return speed;
  }



  function getRandomColor() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      color += letters[Math.round(Math.random() * 15)];
    }
    return color;
  }


  function animate() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.clientWidth, canvas.clientWidth);
    ctx.fillRect(choosenPos, currentPos, 20, 20);
    currentPos += choosenSpeed;
    if (currentPos >= canvas.height) {
      currentPos = 0;
      choosenSpeed = getSpeed();
      choosenPos = getSquare();
      ctx.fillStyle = getRandomColor();
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  }
  start.addEventListener('click', animate);

  stop.removeEventListener('click', animate); //???
};
```

```css
canvas {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button id="start"> Start </button>
  <button id="stop"> Stop </button>
  <span> Score: <span id="score"> 0 </span> </span>
</div>
<canvas width="640" height="480" id="canvas"></canvas>
```

При нажатии на кнопку "Stop" ничего не происходит.

Comment: почему ты думаешь, что при нажатии на кнопку `Stop` что-то должно было происходить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо  анимацию останавливать, а не событие удалять...

```js
window.onload = function() {

  var start = document.getElementById('start');
  var stop = document.getElementById('stop');
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var choosenPos = getSquare();
  var choosenSpeed = getSpeed();
  var currentPos = 0;

  function getSquare() {
    var pos = Math.floor(Math.random() * (640 - 1) + 1);
    return pos;
  }

  function getSpeed() {
    var speed = Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 - 1) + 1);
    return speed;
  }

  function getRandomColor() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      color += letters[Math.round(Math.random() * 15)];
    }
    return color;
  }

  var stoping = null; //добавленные строки в коде

  function animate() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.clientWidth, canvas.clientWidth);
    ctx.fillRect(choosenPos, currentPos, 20, 20);
    currentPos += choosenSpeed;
    if (currentPos >= canvas.height) {
      currentPos = 0;
      choosenSpeed = getSpeed();
      choosenPos = getSquare();
      ctx.fillStyle = getRandomColor();
    }
    stoping = requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  }
  start.addEventListener('click', animate);

  stop.addEventListener('click', function() {
    cancelAnimationFrame(stoping); //добавленные строки в коде
  }); //Добавленная функция
};
```

```html
<style>
  canvas {
    background: yellow;
  }
</style>

<div>
  <button id="start"> Start </button>
  <button id="stop"> Stop </button>
  <span> Score: <span id="score"> 0 </span> </span>
</div>
<canvas width="640" height="480" id="canvas"></canvas>
```